# How to obtain latitude and longitude of a user by IP address or pinpoint location

Tags: php, google-maps, google-chrome

I want to get the geolocation (latitude and longitude) of a computer user by a php script. I was using this one

```
<?php

// Get lat and long by address      
        $address = $dlocation; // Google HQ
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

?>
```

but the problem is that this uses **real adresses** and I just want the user to log in, ask him for the permission to track him (allow location) and if he accepts obtain the desired values (longitude and latitude). It could be by an **IP adress** or another way to pinpoint his location but the thing is I wanted this method to be ***pratically*** flawless regarding proxies and fakies. Any idea on how I could do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: are you ok with gettting the longitude and latitude using user pincode.?

Comment: @Mrcoder if it happens to be "the most exact possible", as in "reasonable", yes. Sometimes you log in to a website and we are asked if we want to give information about our location (normally this is a request made by the browser itself). That's what I was trying to search for...

Comment: i answered a similar question a month ago,this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764303/auto-fill-country-and-city-from-zip-code-and-the-oposite/19764593#19764593

Comment: @Mrcoder ty, but as I said I don't want the user to supply anything but the permission to share his location :p just like this https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en if I get it to work on chrome I'll try to fix something similar in other browsers. Any idea?

Comment: posted an answer,if you are open to html5 then this is the best you can get,go through the source i shared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

download geoip.inc - http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php-20120410/geoip.inc,
geoipcity.inc - http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php-20120410/geoipcity.inc,
geoipregionvars.php - http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php-20120410/geoipregionvars.php,

GeoLiteCity.dat - http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
please convert GeoLiteCity.dat.gz to GeoLiteCity.dat and
put in geoip named folder

```
    include("application/libraries/geoip/geoipcity.inc");
    include("application/libraries/geoip/geoipregionvars.php");

    $giCity = geoip_open("application/libraries/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);

    $ip =$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $record = geoip_record_by_addr($giCity, $ip);

    echo "Getting Country and City detail by IP Address <br /><br />";
    echo "IP: " . $ip . "<br /><br />";

    echo "Country Code: " . $record->country_code .  "<br />" .
    "Country Code3: " . $record->country_code . "<br />" .
    "Country Name: " . $record->country_name . "<br />" .
    "Region Code: " . $record->region . "<br />" .
    "Region Name: " . $GEOIP_REGION_NAME[$record->country_code][$record->region] . "<br />" .
    "City: " . $record->city . "<br />" .
    "Postal Code: " . $record->postal_code . "<br />" .
    "Latitude: " . $record->latitude . "<`enter code here`br />" .
    "Longitude: " . $record->longitude . "<br />" .
    "Metro Code: " . $record->metro_code . "<br />" .
    "Area Code: " . $record->area_code . "<br />" ;
```

Comment: Guys update the link 
now please follow updated links

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you want.simple and easy to use.Thanks to HTML5 [see source here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I see! That's exactly it with a minor flaw :p javascript can be easily defected, so the position kept on the webserver can be flawed... is there a way to hide it or do this exact thing with php?

Comment: basically here we are taking the info from the user browser so i think php wont be of much help unless you supply something to php manually which it will execute in server like in the earlier link i shared with you.

Comment: and its upto you how you are saving the address in your server.

Comment: I see... ty for your help, I'll try and see if I can workaround with something else :b