# find exact lat and long using ip address

Tags: php, google-maps

How can i find the exact latitude and longitude using the ip address.

I am using the below to find the stuff,

```
echo var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])))
```

But my issue is, i am not getting the exact lat and long. Its showing the nearby locations.

Thanks,

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: That is all this service can provide, IP address doesn't provide an EXACT geographical location to web servers. I would strongly recommend reading their own documentation on their website; http://www.geoplugin.com/ - You may be better off finding a plugin that interacts with the browser to request a location, this requires users permission (much like http://maps.google.com/ if you try to centre on your own location) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: You cannot get exact latitude and longitude using the ip address.

But if you want to get latitude and longitude using the ip address you can take reference from here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769064/how-to-obtain-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-user-by-ip-address-or-pinpoint-locatio

Answer (score 2):

ip-adresses do not have a known and exact lat/long (and are often dynamic). 
The geo-ip services give an estimation and use some databases which are not always up-to-date. 
What you usually get is the location of the service provider.

If it is for a website than you can ask the browser to try to get the location. This is however not always working, for example when they don't have/use GPS or WIFI. 
more info here 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp