# shipping restriction based on the selected currency

Tags: magento, currency

I need to implement shipping restriction based on the selected currency.

For example:

If people select / use US dollars to check out, their delivery address can only be in USA, and if people select GBP in currency drop down, their delivery address can only be in UK.

Anyone know how can I achieve that? I am a junior developer and this is my first Maganto project.

Here is my available.phtml file:

```
<?php $_shippingRateGroups = $this->getShippingRates(); ?>
            <?php if (!$_shippingRateGroups): ?>
                <p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.') ?></p>
            <?php else: ?>
                <dl class="sp-methods">
                <?php $shippingCodePrice = array(); ?>
                <?php $_sole = count($_shippingRateGroups) == 1; foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul>
                        <?php $_sole = $_sole && count($_rates) == 1; foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                            <?php $shippingCodePrice[] = "'".$_rate->getCode()."':".(float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>
                            <li>
                               <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?></li></ul></li></ul>
                               <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php if ($_sole) : ?>
                                    <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" checked="checked" /></span>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                    <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>

                                    <?php if ($_rate->getCode() === $this->getAddressShippingMethod()): ?>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        //<![CDATA[
                                            lastPrice = <?php echo (float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>;
                                        //]]>
                                    </script>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </label>
                               <?php endif ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                <?php if (!empty($shippingCodePrice)): ?>
                    var shippingCodePrice = {<?php echo implode(',',$shippingCodePrice); ?>};
                <?php endif; ?>

                $$('input[type="radio"][name="shipping_method"]').each(function(el){
                    Event.observe(el, 'click', function(){
                        if (el.checked == true) {
                            var getShippingCode = el.getValue();
                            <?php if (!empty($shippingCodePrice)): ?>
                                var newPrice = shippingCodePrice[getShippingCode];
                                if (!lastPrice) {
                                    lastPrice = newPrice;
                                    quoteBaseGrandTotal += newPrice;
                                }
                                if (newPrice != lastPrice) {
                                    quoteBaseGrandTotal += (newPrice-lastPrice);
                                    lastPrice = newPrice;
                                }
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;
                            return false;
                        }
                   });
                });
            //]]>
            </script>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the shipping methods according to the currency type. just go to the
 `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method\available.phtml` and get the currency by getting cart over here. And now by simple If/Else conditions according to the currency you can restrict the shipping methods.

Comment: you can do the same by verifying the zip code according to the payment. write a ajax code for validating zip

Comment: Thank you for your help, you already explained me a lot. But I still have a problem with how to implement that. The way I understand it is:                               <?php
$usa_shipping = true;  // allowed by default 
$uk_shipping = true;   // allowed by default 

$currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

if($currency_code == "USD") {
        $uk_shipping = false;
    } elseif($currency_code == "GBP") {
        $uk_shipping = true;
 
    }
?>

Comment: How can I implement it into the actual checkout process ?

Comment: call ajax and pass the zip code from shipping address. and use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764303/auto-fill-country-and-city-from-zip-code-and-the-oposite. for checking the country according to the zip code.

Comment: Could you please be more specific. I am not familiar with Ajax. This is also my first magento project. Your first solution sim to be logic. Could you advise me how can I implement that. Thanks

Comment: I will provide you. just give me sometime.